# Multiple synks of trhe same type from configuration

Tags: configuration, serilog

Using [Serilog.Settings.Configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration), is it possible to specify multiple synks of the same type? For example, logging as plain text to a file and logging as JSON to another file.

Can it be done in the Async synk too?

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using":  ["Serilog.Sinks.File"],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "File", "Args": { "path": "%TEMP%\\Logs\\serilog-configuration-sample1.txt" } },
      { "Name": "File", "Args": { "path": "%TEMP%\\Logs\\serilog-configuration-sample2.txt" } }
    ],
    "Enrich": ["FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId"],
    "Properties": {
        "Application": "Sample"
    }
  }
}
```

Or:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using":  ["Serilog.Sinks.File"],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": {
      "1": { "Name": "File", "Args": { "path": "%TEMP%\\Logs\\serilog-configuration-sample1.txt" } },
      "2": { "Name": "File", "Args": { "path": "%TEMP%\\Logs\\serilog-configuration-sample2.txt" } }
    },
    "Enrich": ["FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId"],
    "Properties": {
        "Application": "Sample"
    }
  }
}
```